# How can I pin more than four sites to the left vertical bar in the iPad app?

Tags: support, ios-app, ipad

I tried to see if I could pin more than 4 sites on the left bar because I'm a user on several sites, but I couldn't find a way to do it. In the Android app I have all the sites I'm subscribed to on the left bar but I'm not sure how to do it in this app.

[image: Stack Exchange iPad app screenshot showing pinned sites]

Comment: I have a bunch pinned, but i set it from the web.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: I just edited the community list online.

Comment: I'll try, the problem is that I don't find the edit button

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9NAQz.png

Comment: What a stupid, the edit button was right in front of me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in the iPhone and iPad apps as well as on desktop (they are synched between them).

On the iPhone it's more visible because you actually have to open the menu to see the sites but on both the steps are:

1. Tap the three line menu icon on the top left corner of the navigation bar:

   [image: Screenshot highlighting the menu button.]
2. Tap "Edit" in the header above the first site in the menu:

   [image: Screenshot of the expanded menu, highlighting the Edit button.]
3. Tap the plus (+) button to add a site and use the edit controls to move sites around or delete them from the menu:

   [image: Screenshot of the Pinned Sites screen, highlighting the Add button.]