# Unlink site in iOS app?

Tags: support, ios-app

When visiting an unpinned site in the iOS app you tap-hold on the site icon to "pin" the site.  However, tap-hold on a pinned site icon does not present an option to unpin the site. How does one remove a site from the site bar?

Comment: You should have "edit" option as seen [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251426/152859) - when tapping it, don't you get option to unpin sites? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tap the **Edit** button on the right of the Sites separator, then unpin the site by tapping the red minus and then Delete.

[image]
[image]